# Play Framework 2.2 (java) WS recovery block does not catch HTTP exception

Tags: java, exception, playframework-2.2, recovery

(Seemingly) simple static method that invokes a known good web service.

Service returns HTTP 500 / Internal Server Error if a matching record is not found, but the recovery block of invokation is never executed.

Am I missing the obvious or doing something blatantly stupid?

```
public static Promise<Property> ByPhone(String phone) {
  return WS.url("http://localhost:9000/data/property/" + phone)
           .get ()
           .map (
              new Function<WS.Response, Property>() {
                public Property apply (WS.Response response) {
                  System.out.println("got here: " + response.getStatusText());
                  Property property = null;
                  try {
                    property = _mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Property.class);
                  } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return property;
                }
              }
            ).recover (
              new Function<Throwable, Property>() {
                public Property apply (Throwable t) {
                  System.out.println("never get here");
                  t.printStackTrace();
                  return null;
                }
              }
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recover` helps one recover from uncaught exceptions. In this case an HTTP 500 response doesn't result in an uncaught `Throwable`

Presumably, 500 means that the following block will throw an error

```
property = _mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Property.class);
```

However, you have this wrapped in a try catch block already.

Comment: Bah, spot on.  Holdover from my .NET mentality where client WILL throw on a server exception.  Thanks for kick in head.  Sorta figured it out when server was not reachable and recover DID fire, but hadn't dug in to prove it.